# trying to Recover an HFS+ Partition The table looks fine but Disk Utility and fsck_hfs failed

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, data-recovery, hfs+

I have been trying to recover my partition, on another mac, running Sierra, first I tried the usual, disk utility, and I got a list of "missing thread record" like this
[image: These are the errors after I execute fsck_hfs -r on /dev/disk2s2/ the partition I am working on to fix.]

Then I moved into TestDisk and I was able to see a fine partition table, I also checked the S.M.A.R.T. before and it's Verified, the partition table I see is this >>>

[image: Partition table on disk2, with the partition I want to recover highlighted]

Now What I want is to see what can I do to attempt recovering, after I unmounted the HD Recovery partition disk2s3, I was able to write the partition table to the disk, as shown in the image above., but that's it ... I am not able to see anything else nor do any more progress ... BTW First Aid Hangs up when and displays an error when I try to check disk2s2, both the EFI and Recovery are ok ... Before it was showing the partition's name now it's gone ...

Comment: You've got a backup of the data and don't want to seek professional data recovery services - correct? If you keep writing to the disk, you shut the door to a faster / less expensive / recovery.

Comment: Look, what I want is an alternative method, not a ridiculous comment of something that's obvious ... if I were a non-tech maybe I won't, but no it's not going to cost me a penny just my time ...

Comment: What is displayed when you type “Diskutil list”?  Are you checking the disks remotely? if so, have you tried repairing the disk by placing the HD in an external enclosure? Or on the actual system via recovery/single user?